# How to make a WPF custom control which inherits from WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, custom-controls

I got some trouble with a WPF customcontrol which inherits from the WPF datagrid and need some advice.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm working with VS2015 and C# on a WPF application in which i'm using - among the standard WPF controls - selfmade custom controls.

Now i wanted to make a new custom control which inherits from the WPF datagrid, so i have the possibility to overwrite the OnItemsSourceChanged-event.

As long as i'm not using explicit defined columns in the datagrid all is fine and it looks like the standard WPF datagrid.

But i have a few problems.

First events like SelectionChanged don't work anymore because i don't raise the event from the inner datagrid of my custom control to the parent.

How shall i do that?

Next, am i able to use explicit defined columns?

Here some samples of the custom control definition and how i use it in one of my WPF windows:

First the definition of the custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DataGrid BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{TemplateBinding ColumnHeaderStyle}"
                              ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                              CanUserAddRows="{TemplateBinding CanUserAddRows}"
                              IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the usage in one of the WPF windows.
Please pay attention that one of my colleagues had implemented a grid filter.
Do i have to inherit the filter as the properties of the parent datagrid?

```
                    <CustomControls:CustomDataGrid x:Name="grdInputMasksList"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          filter:DataGridExtensions.UseBackgroundWorkerForFiltering="True"
                          filter:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False"
                          filter:DataGridExtensions.IsFilterVisible="True"
                          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl},ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding InputMasksListShortDetails}"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          SelectionChanged="grdInputMasksList_SelectionChanged"
                          MouseDoubleClick="grdInputMasksList_MouseDoubleClick">
                        <CustomControls:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TextDelete" filter:DataGridColumnExtensions.DoNotGenerateFilterControl="True">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Name="btnRemoveInputMask"
                                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                        Width="30" Height="20" Focusable="False"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding inputMaskId}"
                                        Click="btnRemoveInputMask_Click">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Source="..\..\pictures\delete_blue.png"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colInputMaskName"
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=inputMaskName}"
                                            Header="TextInputMaskName"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="colIsReleased" 
                                                Binding="{Binding isReleasedBool}" 
                                                Header="TextIsReleasedShort"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colInputMaskText"
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=text}"
                                            Header="TextPropertyDescriptionText"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colInputMaskChanger"
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=changedBy}"
                                            Header="TextChangedBy"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colInputMaskChangeDate"
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=changeDate, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm'}"
                                            Header="TextChangeDate"/>
                        </CustomControls:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
                    </CustomControls:CustomDataGrid>
```

Comment: You should recycle the default template for DataGrid and alter it according to your needs. Then you’ll get all the normal behavior you want. Right click on a regular WPF DataGrid in the XAML designer and select “Edit Template” from the context menu.